# Changing the Position of Axis Values and Labels in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some questions regarding formatting in matplotlib. I have a matrix and am plotting it using plt.matshow(). I'm struggling to make it look nice. My code is as follows:

```
norm_conf_mx = 
norm_conf_mx =  np.array([[5728,    3,   24,   10,   11,   51,   44,    8,   40,    4],
                       [   1, 6484,   42,   27,    6,   51,    6,   10,  105,   10],
                       [  52,   34, 5337,  108,   79,   23,   91,   54,  164,   16],
                       [  47,   40,  137, 5335,    2,  243,   37,   62,  139,   89],
                       [  19,   25,   36,    8, 5385,   12,   54,   32,   81,  190],
                       [  73,   35,   33,  183,   78, 4631,  102,   27,  173,   86],
                       [  37,   23,   52,    2,   47,   93, 5615,    3,   45,    1],
                       [  26,   20,   70,   30,   47,   10,    8, 5820,   17,  217],
                       [  49,  146,   71,  155,   18,  165,   56,   25, 5027,  139],
                       [  43,   33,   25,   94,  168,   34,    3,  204,   89, 5256]])



nums = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
my_ticks = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.matshow(norm_conf_mx,cmap="gray",fignum=1)
plt.ylabel('Actual Class')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Class') 
plt.xticks(nums, my_ticks)
plt.yticks(nums, my_ticks)
plt.show()
```

This yields the diagram:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiH07.png)

Why are the x axis values (what is the terminology for the numbers labelled on the axis?) at the top?

How do I go about moving them to the bottom?

How could I place the label "Predicted Class" to the top?

Is there a better way to set the values of the labels on the axes? e.g. without defining an np.array and ticks?

Thanks alot!

Comment: You should search for a question like this. There are plenty of answers on StackOverflow already and in the Matplotlib documentation.

Comment: @Denziloe I could not find any that worked in my situation - I apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc of `plt.matshow`

> Tick labels for the xaxis are placed on top.

As [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) suggests, you can use `plt.gca().xaxis.set_label_position('top')` to move the x label.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.matshow(norm_conf_mx,cmap="gray",fignum=1)
plt.ylabel('Actual Class')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Class')
plt.xticks(nums, my_ticks)
plt.yticks(nums, my_ticks)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_label_position('top')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can use `plt.imshow` to show the x axis values in the botton

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(norm_conf_mx,cmap="gray",)
plt.ylabel('Actual Class')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Class') 
plt.xticks(nums, my_ticks)
plt.yticks(nums, my_ticks)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `labelpad=-600` is not useful. Use `plt.gca().xaxis.set_label_position('top')` instead.